# Error In Database Renaming

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I need to rename one of my database and tried a query like this

```
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY NAME = NewTest
```

But this throws an error

```
    Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
```

Can any one give me any suggestion?

Comment: Use Activity Monitor to kill off any existing connections to the database you want to rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like;

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test 
SET SINGLE_USER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY NAME = NewTest
GO
ALTER DATABASE NewTest
SET MULTI_USER 
GO
```

Be aware of the fact that this may not rename the physical file on the hard drive though.

Comment: Query worked fine for me.But i think you need to change it a little bit ALTER DATABASE Test SET MULTI_USER  need to be changed as ALTER DATABASE NewTest
SET MULTI_USER

Comment: And can you plz give me any suggestion to rename physical file

Comment: Quite right AKS! Well spotted! Glad it worked for you though!

Comment: This looks like a good post on the subject... http://sqlandme.com/2011/08/02/sql-server-renaming-database-and-physical-database-files/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to investigate. The reason you're getting that error could be due to one or more of the following things:

1. The account you're using does not have permission to run the command
2. The DB is locked by another process/user
3. The database contains a file group that is read-only

You can try and force single user mode to check 2.

`ALTER DATABASE SINGLE_USER ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE.`

That will kill any concurrent connections to the DB allowing you to rule out number two.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Look for and kill all connections like OMG Priories suggest
2. Open the database in Single Server Mode as described here: 
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598(v=sql.105).aspx